# Wordpress - creating meta boxes and saving

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, meta-boxes

I'm trying to create a metabox, it should be nice and easy but I'm getting it wrong. It pertains to a tour custom post, and adding the price in for that tour:

So initially I create this custom post type (this works):

```
register_post_type( 'tours',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Tours' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'Tour' ),
                    'add_new' => 'Add New Tour Instance',
                    'add_new_item' => 'Add New Tour Instance',
                    'edit' => 'Edit',
                    'edit_item' => 'Edit Tour Instance',
                    'new_item' => 'New Tour Instance',
                    'view' => 'View',
                    'view_item' => 'View Tour Instance',
                    'search_items' => 'Search Tour Instances',
                    'not_found' => 'No Tour Instances found',
                    'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Tour Instances found in Rubbish',
                    'parent' => 'Parent Tour Instance'
                ),
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail'),
            'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
            //'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'images/image.png', __FILE__ ),
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'rewrite' => array("slug" => "tours") // Permalinks format
            )
        );
```

Then I create the box itself (this also works):

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'tour_meta' );
        function tour_meta() {
            add_meta_box(
                'tours_meta_box',
                'Tour Price',
                'display_tours_price_meta_box',
                'tours',
                'side',
                'high'
            );
        }
```

Now, within the overall function, I then try to get the detail and save it:

```
function display_tours_price_meta_box() {
            global $post;
            // Noncename needed to verify where the data originated
            echo '<input type="hidden" name="tourmeta_noncename" id="tourmeta_noncename" value="' . 
            wp_create_nonce( plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) . '" />';

            // Get the price data if its already been entered
            $price = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_price', true);
            echo 'Add the total cost for this tour here, do not include monetary characters like £ or $';
            echo '<input type="text" name="_price" ' . $price  . '" class="widefat" />';
        }
        function save_tours_meta($tour_id, $tour) {
            if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['tourmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) {
            return $post->ID;
            }
            // Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
            if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID ))
                return $post->ID;

            $tour_meta['_price'] = $_POST['_price'];

            // Add values of $tour_meta as custom fields
            foreach ($tour_meta as $key => $value) {
                if( $post->post_type == 'revision' ) return;
                $value = implode(',', (array)$value);
                if(get_post_meta($post->ID, $key, FALSE)) {
                    update_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
                } else {
                    add_post_meta($post->ID, $key, $value);
                }
                if(!$value) delete_post_meta($post->ID, $key);
            }
        }
        add_action('save_post', 'save_tours_meta', 1, 2);
```

The actual box appears, and the information is echo'd. However it does not save. I haven't the foggiest why. It must pertain to my last function, but I don't understand what is going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should better simplify your saving process like this :

```
    function save_tours_meta($post_id) {
        if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['tourmeta_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) ))       {
        // You don't need to return anything
        return;
        }
        // Is the user allowed to edit the post or page?
        if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) && !isset($_POST['_price']))
            return;

        // If you just have 1 value
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_price', $_POST['_price']);
    }
```

Just notice that the `update_post_meta` function will **update** the post meta or **create** it if it doesn't exist so don't bother usind `add_post_meta`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's your arguments.  You declare the function as

```
function save_tours_meta($tour_id, $tour) {
```

but you're using (eg) `$post->ID`.  `$post` in this case isn't the global variable, but the function argument.  Try using `$tour->ID` or just `$tour_id` instead.

A couple of other (unrelated) things:

1. You can call `update_post_meta()` and it'll add the key if it doesn't exist, so you can remove your `if` statement (just reducing the lines of code).
2. Your "revision" check should return the post ID (and can be moved outside your loop)